# XIB compatible with both iOS 5 and iOS 7

Tags: ios5, uiview, ios7, xcode5

I discovered an Interface Bulder option named `iOS6/7 deltas`. Ok, I used this to set a free room for status bar (basically, I reduced `UIViewController` view contents height by 20pt and changed origin to 20pt). It worked fine, iOS 6 and iOS 7 look the same, but after that I installed it to iOS 5. Well, how can I fix that? Status bar shouldn't overlap contents, also there shouldn't be black space in the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be, the nib decoder implementation in iOS5 cannot cope with the values set in Xcode. My suggestion would be to perform your view "fixes" in code, after loading your view. You should also consider dropping support for iOS5, as it has a very small market share.

Comment: In `viewWillAppear` the correct frame was changed by UIKit. I had to set the root navigation controller's frame manually to {0, 20, 320, 460} and manually handle status bar hiding. Also `UIWindow` in main NIB file now have the size of R3.5, not of R4 like before. It seems to work good now. I totally agree with your argument for drop the iOS 5 support, on this app it about 2% (600) users, but my customer thinks other way.